# Dawnguard DLC disappears after turning off Xbox

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I have been playing Dawnguard for awhile now and I got up to the mission where you get the dragon Elder Scroll. After I got it I saved, turned off my xbox and went to bed. When I got up next morning my dlc was gone but I still had the scroll...

I reinstalled it but now I can't even get the guard to tell me about the Dawnguard or talk to anybody inside the fort. Anybody got any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have access to Xbox live? You can't play DLC or downloaded games if you aren't connected to the internet.

Comment: Yes you can, if it is downloaded to the Xbox for the first time it will be registered to it, allowing online and offline play.

Comment: I cannot tell you how to stop this problem from happening, but I can tell you how to fix the situation each time it uninstalls. It happened to me once, dawnguard had uninstalled, so my character was just a normal vampire,all my dawnguard items were simply gone. So, I reinstalled and loaded the the last save before the uninstall. I hope it helps :)

Comment: If the fort is still there, the DLC should be there too, so something else is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

**If Fort Dawnguard, Castle Volkihar, etc. *exist*, then the DLC is still installed.**

Your question implies that you visited Dayspring Canyon and verified that Fort Dawnguard is still there. If that is not the case, and the fort (or the entire entrance to Dayspring Canyon) is actually gone, then you should reinstall the game and load your last save from before the DLC disappeared (do not attempt to load a save you made while the game was broken).

The Elder Scroll itself is from the base game, and not the DLC. Thus, it will not vanish if the DLC gets uninstalled. The DLC does, however, rename it to "Elder Scroll (Dragon)," so you can look at the name in your inventory to see whether that rename is still in effect. If it's just called "Elder Scroll," then the DLC is most likely gone.

If the Fort is still there and the Elder Scroll is still labeled "(Dragon)," you do not have a "vanishing DLC" problem but a "quest fails to progress" problem. The broken quest is *probably* one of the following quests:

- [Seeking Disclosure](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Seeking_Disclosure) and/or [Scroll Scouting](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Scroll_Scouting) seem to best fit your symptoms, but these quests are very simple and I can't seriously imagine either one breaking in the manner you describe.
- [Discerning the Transmundane](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane) is much more complicated, and I could imagine it breaking, but I'm not really convinced that this would cause problems for you if you have actually obtained the Elder Scroll from it.
- [Chasing Echoes](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Chasing_Echoes) is for the other Scroll. I don't think it's relevant to this.
- You should have already completed [Prophet](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Prophet_(Dawnguard)), so that probably isn't relevant either.

Each quest has a bugs section which you should consult. Unfortunately, the easiest way to fix problems in Skyrim is to use the developer console, which is only accessible on the PC version of the game, and so you might not be able to find a workable fix here. You might have to reload an older save.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends, I have a level 48 Character, randomly my DLC's all delete themselves, I reinstall them, the children in Hearthfire save, but nothing else does, so I have to reinstall it and play it again. I recommend simply reinstalling Skyrim or something along with all the DLC's. Keep your save file if you are doing this! Send it to another storage device then reinstall it!